# Namespace prefix 'bal' is not defined

Tags: wix

I've got this error. Since I put below code in the Bundle.wxs.

```
  <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication.Hyperlink2License">
  <bal:WixExtendedBootstrapperApplication
    ThemeFile="Resources\COTheme.xml"
    LicenseUrl="http://xxxxxx
  />
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```

Could please anyone help me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to add the namespace reference to bal by following

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi" 
        xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
```

I suppose you have to supply -ext WixUtilExtension while compiling and building.

```
candle.exe example.wxs -ext WixBalExtension
light.exe example.wixobj -ext WixBalExtension
```